# How to send call to isdn phone by web based php application?

Tags: php, sockets, pbx, tapi, freepbx

I am looking for a solution for a web based application written in PHP where the users are able to control their isdn phones, primarily sending calls to their phone. I know there is something like Asterik / freepbx but i am not sure wether it's the answer to the task, neither do i know how the setup would be.

Would the client have to install a virtual server with pbx running on their machine? Or can this be achived by some sort of socket interface (TAPI) ?

Any useful hints are appreciated

Comment: We do this by asterisk phoning my phone.. on pickup, it then dials the customer

Comment: thank you for putting me on the right track !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after Farkie gave me the right direction i finally found a useful post that solved my question.

http://www.linux-magazin.de/Ausgaben/2008/01/Zeit-fuer-was-Neues